# Is there any way in Redux form to have checkbox with three options, like positive, negative and not selected?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-redux, redux-form

I am working on a form with three way checkbox - positive, negative or not selected.

I am wondering if is there any good examples of doing that with redux-form Field.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem.StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm curious what is the scenario here? A checkbox seems like not exactly the right element for the job here since a checkbox holds binary information, but you want ternary.

Comment: Good suggestion Henry, however we had checkbox working the way mentioned in old application which we are writing in react now. So if possible, would love not to change the user experience.

Comment: This is the scenario for three option select, not a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Although the perfect UI elements for the UX you are looking for is a , you want a custom UI element, not real checkbox, try with this:

https://github.com/jchiam/react-three-state-checkbox

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it like this:

```
  <Field
    type="checkbox"
    name="absolute"
    value="negative"
    validate={[required]}
    component={checkbox}
    label="negative"
  />

 <Field
    type="checkbox"
    name="absolute"
    value="positive"
    validate={[required]}
    component={checkbox}
    label="positive"
  />
```

Initially it will be not selected any value, when any of the value is selected it will be set as positive/negative.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
how can we show right tick, minus tick or empty box based on it?